# interface型をint64型に変換したい

Tags: go

下記のようなinterface型の変数`r`をint64型に変換したいのですができません。

```
fmt.Println(r) => [40]
v := reflect.valueOf(r)
fmt.Println(v.Type()) => []interface{}
fmt.Println(v.Kind()) => slice
```

これを素直に`a, ok := r.(int64)`としても、スライスなので`a, ok := r.([]int64)`としても変換できませんでした。
これはどうやって変換すればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

スライスの要素を一つ一つ変換していく事になります。

```golang
a := make([]int64, len(r))
for i, v := range r {
    switch v.(type) {
    case int64:
        a[i] = v.(int64)
    }
}

fmt.Println(a)  // => [40]
```

ただ、int64 型ではない要素はスキップされますので初期値(0)のままになります。

```golang
r := []interface{}{int64(40), "foo", 100}
fmt.Println(a)  // => [40 0 0]
```

**追記**

`int64` 型に変換可能な型を持つ要素を全て取り込む場合を追記しておきます。

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "reflect"
)

func main() {
  r := []interface{}{int64(40), int(1), float64(1.8), int8(100), int16(2000), int32(30000)}

  fmt.Println(r)
  vr := reflect.ValueOf(r)
  fmt.Println(vr.Type())
  fmt.Println(vr.Kind())

  a := make([]int64, 0, len(r))
  for _, v := range r {
    switch v.(type) {
    case int64:
      a = append(a, v.(int64))
    case int:
      a = append(a, int64(v.(int)))
    case int8:
      a = append(a, int64(v.(int8)))
    case int16:
      a = append(a, int64(v.(int16)))
    case int32:
      a = append(a, int64(v.(int32)))
    }
  }

  fmt.Println(a)
}
```

※ float/float32/float64 型の変数も変換できないことはないのですが、整数値に丸められたり(切り捨て)、overflow を起こす場合もありますので除外しています

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
こちらの方法を試してみましたが、`cannot range over r (type interface {})`というエラーが出てしまいました。

Comment: @zousan `fmt.Println(v.Type()) => []interface{}`, `fmt.Println(v.Kind()) => slice` となっていますので、`r` は `interface{}` のスライスになっていると思うのですが…。

Comment: 今このinterfaceの出処を調べましたが、関数の返り値が指定されていませんでした。このinterfaceの出処は`redigo`というGoのRedis clientのhttps://github.com/garyburd/redigo/blob/master/redisx/connmux.go#L91の箇所みたいです。この場合どう対処すればいいのでしょうか。おそらく返ってきている型はinterfaceのスライス型で間違いありませんが、ビルドできません。

Comment: また、すみません。おそらく呼ばれているのはhttps://github.com/garyburd/redigo/blob/764a32c188f6ce0bc2565349f0125b3ad4021ea9/redis/conn.go#L515 でした。 私が呼び出したのはc.Do("EXEC")という関数で上記の様に[]interface{}型が返ってきました。

Comment: @zousan  `redis/reply.go` にある `Values()` 関数のコメントを読みますと、`c.Do()` の戻り値(reply)には正常値やエラー値などがあるので `[]interface{}` 型にしている様です。reply が正常値の場合は `byte[]` で `type assertion` しています。`redis/conn_test.go` を見ると、`c.Do()` の戻り値をどの様に扱うのかが分かるかと思います。

Comment: できました。`Values()`という関数を使うことで、[]interface{}型に変換できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

この方法でいかがでしょうか？
https://play.golang.org/p/c413UEvofS

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    r := []interface{}{40}
    fmt.Println(r)          // [40]
    v := reflect.ValueOf(r)
    fmt.Println(v.Type())       // []interface {}
    fmt.Println(v.Kind())       // slice

    v2 := reflect.ValueOf(r[0])
    fmt.Println(v2.Type())      // int
    fmt.Println(v2.Kind())      // int

    v3 := reflect.ValueOf(int64(r[0].(int)))
    fmt.Println(v3.Type())      // int64
    fmt.Println(v3.Kind())      // int64
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
こちらの方法を試してみましたが`invalid operation: r[0] (type interface {} does not support indexing)`という実行前エラーが出てしまいました。